# CSV read specific column, if it doesn't exist put NaN

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some CSV files from where I have to read some specific data (columns), but the problem is that some of the files don't have those columns at all. Since I am trying to figure out the quality of the data, and checking for these missing data, whenever I don't find the column at all in the file I want to be able to create it and populate it with NaNs.

Is there a way to do this in python? Pandas?

Thank you in advance for you help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all csv file read into dataframe ,

```
l=[df1,df2,...]


d={x: y.reset_index(level=0,drop=True) for x , y in pd.concat(l,keys=range(len(l))).groupby(level=0)}
```

Then you can accesses the `df` by

```
d[0]
```